MetaMask issue with wallet
Cant seem to slove this issue as you can see below I have a wallet that I cant use  the funds
0xa9e3...408f76
0xa9e3...408f76
$74.56  Watched Unowned
I have tried everything and Im at lost why does it say Watched Unowned . I even reached Customer care but Im getting the run around can anyone help me with this ..
Thank you
